# Acumatica: Update Vendor Status when TaxRegistrationID changes

Tags: c#, customization, acumatica

I am brand new to Acumatica and need to do something very simple but am not really understanding the syntax or how to go about it.

I want to update Vendor Status to "Hold" if the TaxRegistrationID changes in the Purchase Settings tab.  It seems very simple but I am just not getting the right steps.  I started here:

```
public class VendorMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<VendorMaint>
{
#region Event Handlers
    protected void LocationExtAddress_TaxRegistrationID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
     {
      cache.SetValue<Vendor.Status>(e.Row, "Hold");  

      }

#endregion
}
```

I think that is oversimplifying it, but not sure what it should be.  Can someone give me a little guidance here?  I can get a long way on my own if i understand how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did very good. You have still few issues.
1. In Acumatica field status declarations for

```
[Vendor.status.List]
```

looks like this:

```
public class ListAttribute : PXStringListAttribute
  {
    public ListAttribute()
      : base(new string[5]{ "A", "H", "P", "I", "T" }, new string[5]
      {
        "Active",
        "On Hold",
        "Hold Payments",
        "Inactive",
        "One-Time"
      })
    {
    }
  }
}
```

as you can see from declaration of Status for On Hold is responsible key value "H".

2. Field TaxRegistrationID on it's page declaration doesn't have CommitChanges set to true. If you want immediate reaction, you'll need to set CommitChanges to true in customization.
3. Instead of updating cache object, you need to update particular vendor.
4. On vendors screen it is used not Vendor class, but VendorR class

So more correct version of code will look like this:

```
     public class VendorMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<VendorMaint>
     {
        #region Event Handlers
        protected void LocationExtAddress_TaxRegistrationID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
              Base.BAccount.SetValueExt<VendorR.status>(Base.BAccount.Current, "H"); 

        }

        #endregion
     }
```

Comment: Thank you Yuriy,
I tried a few variations and nothing is actually working.  The SetValue isn’t setting the Vendor Status value to Hold or “H”.  Is there another step I need to set the Vendor status to Hold?

Comment: I found your blog and the answer.  This works…so thank you!:

Base.BAccount.SetValueExt<VendorR.status>(Base.BAccount.Current, "H");

Comment: Oh, yeah, that is another approach. Can you tell if updated answer reflects changes you took from my blog, and if yes, can you mark my answer as accepted?